# MySQL group by Date, but output month name

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, grouping

I'm around 70% sure this is doable, I seem to remember I did something similar a few years ago, but have since forgotten how to do it (if I ever did).

Basically, I have a table in MySQL with an 'uploaded_date' field.

The format of the date is D/M/YYYY

I know how to group and order by the date, however I'd like to return the date as a month name. For example:

**September**:

- Result
- Result
- Result

**October**:

- Result
- Result
- Result

Etc..

Is there an easy way to do this in a MySQL query?

Comment: Are you looking for [`MonthName()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_monthname)

Comment: `GROUP BY MONTH(uploaded_date)`

Comment: Fix the date data type

Comment: You should do the final formatting of the results in the application. To generate the exact output you describe is possible in MySQL, but requires a more complicated query, than repeating the month name in every record.

Comment: merely do the the group by. But have an additional wrapper for monthname at the end. So an extra outer loop.